# Tridion Docs 14SP2: Can we enable Spell check in Draft and Review space?

Tags: tridion-docs

As we know that Spell check functionality in Draft space and Review space is being introduced in the 14SP4 version.

Can we do some configuration updates to make this feature available in Docs 14SP2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible as you need an extra service **"Trisoft InfoShare ContentQuality"** on the application server to let Spell Checking work and that just is not there in 14SP2. It's supported only from Tridion Docs 14SP4.

**Note:** please note that Quality Check only supported in Draft Space not Review space.

Comment: Thank you Velmurugan for the clarification on this regard. So, this Spell check functionality will only work in Draft Space and not in Review space even in Tridion Docs 14SP4. Or this functionality may need some configuration update in order to make it work in SP4 Review space.

Comment: @SDLBeginner Review Space not supported, It's not possible to enable, It should work only on Draft Space

Comment: Thank you so much for this information Velmurugan.